# why ({}+{})="[object Object][object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have tested the code:

```
{}+{} = NaN;
({}+{}) = "[object Object][object Object]";
```

Why does adding the `()` change the result?

Comment: because `{}` is an object.. not a number..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{}+{}` is a *block* followed by an expression. The first `{}` is the block (like the kind you attach to an `if` statement), the `+{}` is the expression. The first `{}` is a block because when the parser is looking for a statement and sees `{`, it interprets it as the opening of a block. That block, being empty, does nothing. Having processed the block, the parser sees the `+` and reads it as a unary `+`. That shifts the parser into handling an expression. In an expression, a `{` starts an object initializer instead of a block, so the `{}` is an object initializer. The object initializer creates an object, which `+` then tries to coerce to a number, getting `NaN`.

In `({}+{})`, the opening `(` shifts the parser into the mode where it's expecting an expression, not a statement. So the `()` contains *two* object initializers with a *binary* `+` (e.g., the "addition" operator, which can be arithmetic or string concatenation) between them. The binary `+` operator will attempt to add or concatenate depending on its operands. It coerces its operands to primitives, and in the case of `{}`, they each become the string `"[object Object]"`. So you end up with `"[object Object][object Object]"`, the result of concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

Because of ambiguity. `{}` is an object but also a block boundary. Without `()` it is interpreted as the latter.